# AttributedText in TextView while typing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, uitextviewdelegate

I have a textView, and I am trying to give it an attributed text. I tried achieving it inside `shouldChangeTextInRange`, but it crashes for range out of index.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool { 

   if myTextView {
      textView.attributedText = addAttributedText(1, text: text, fontsize: 13)

      let newText = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)
      let numberOfChars = newText.characters.count

      return numberOfChars < 20
   }
   return true
}

 func addAttributedText(spacing:CGFloat, text:String, fontsize: CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(
        name: "Font",
        size: fontsize)!])
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: spacing, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))
    return attributedString

}
```

I tried adding attributedString with empty text to textView in viewDidLoad, but that doesn't help. That's why I thought it would be appropriate to do it on `shouldChangeTextInRange`

(Please note that my `addAttributedText` method works perfectly for other textviews)

If I use this, in one character type-in, it writes 2x and crashes. What is the right way of handling that kind of converting textView's text to attributed text that is being typed.

Comment: have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716525/replace-uitextviews-text-with-attributed-string

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin Unfortunately, this type of objective-c seems confusing to me as I don't have any prior knowledge. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that I tried to convert from the link above, it might have bugs, but I hope it will be able to help you.

```
func formatTextInTextView(textView: UITextView) 
{
    textView.scrollEnabled = false
    var selectedRange: NSRange = textView.selectedRange
    var text: String = textView.text!
    // This will give me an attributedString with the base text-style
    var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var regex: NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression.regularExpressionWithPattern("#(\\w+)", options: 0, error: error!)
    var matches: [AnyObject] = regex.matchesInString(text, options: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))

    for match: NSTextCheckingResult in matches {
        var matchRange: NSRange = match.rangeAtIndex(0)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: matchRange)
    }
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
    textView.selectedRange = selectedRange
    textView.scrollEnabled = true
}
```

EDIT: didn't see that in the original post there was a Swift answer, here is the link: [stackoverflow.com/a/35842523/1226963](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35842523/1226963)

Comment: there is a swift version here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35842523/4705339 it works perfectly

Comment: Great!!! Glad it helped!

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin This answer was plagiarized from http://stackoverflow.com/a/35842523/1226963 with no attribution. Do not post other people's answer as your own.

Comment: first, I posted the link to it. senty asked me if I can convert it, and I did using this link: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code. senty actually found the swift version that you're referring to later, and it's in the comments. Am I guilty, that my answer was marked as an answer?

Comment: I can add a reference to this post no problem